# How to copy local group policy objects from one machine to another?

Tags: windows-7, security, group-policy

I have two Windows 7 Professional desktops. One has a set of local (no Domain Controller) group policy objects imposing restrictions on what programs can be run from that system. I need to copy all those GPOs to another local Windows 7 Pro machine. Is there any way to automate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to copy the answer from [the source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itproxpsp/thread/2030e62e-a60d-442a-8455-647b569caffb) in case it gets deleted or closed:

> 1.) Open `%systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy\`
>
> Within this folder, there are two folders - `machine` and `user`. Copy these to folders to the `%systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy` - folder on the target machine. 
>   Restart the machine or run `GPUPDATE /force`
>
> Note :- `%systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy` is a hidden folder. You need
>   to enable viewing of hidden folders in explorer.
>
> 2) [Use the Security Configuration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742512.aspx)

Comment: On my system, these folders exist, but the files inside are very small, i.e. registry.pol only has 8 Bytes, so no reasonable content. The question is: if I want to store everything I can see in gpedit.msc (including all trees with all subfolders on the left side), how can all this be exported?